# GPU Issue can get into windows without drivers - BSOD

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

I was on my PC and suddenly my computer shutdown and booted into a bsod. I suspected it was the gpu because of the dollar signs at the beginning of the boot and so I proceeded to install the latest driver for my 560Ti, didn't work, tried an old driver from a little more than 6 months, also didn't work.

Having done the process above I tried it again with Display drive uninstaller, with no luck.

[image: BSOD image]

Errors from the event logs:

1.

> 1. Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent
>      WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND
>      TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in
>      namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot
>      be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.
> 2. DCOM got error "1068" attempting to start the service fdPHost with
>      arguments "" in order to run the server:
>      {D3DCB472-7261-43CE-924B-0704BD730D5F}
> 3. Fault bucket , type 0 Event Name: BlueScreen Response: Not available
>      Cab Id: 0   Problem signature: P1:  P2:  P3:  P4:  P5:  P6:  P7:  P8: 
>      P9:  P10:    Attached files: C:\Windows\Minidump\052418-15366-01.dmp
>      C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-78031-0.sysdata.xml   These
>      files may be available here:
>      C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Kernel_0_0_cab_07b54bfd
>      Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
>      052418-15366-01 Report Status: 0

Comment: 560TI is an older card, maybe it is damaged now after the years of usage. do you have a CPU with integrated GPU (Intel i5/7) to test if this onboard GPU works?

Comment: I think its defaulting to integrated graphics. By the screen is like 200x200, not sure how to confirm its working.

Comment: nvlddmkm.sys means nVIDIA driver. so look if your CPU has integrated GPU

Answer (score 0):

1. Reboot
2. Hit the F8 key at least once if not 2x a second.

A boot menu will appear.

[image: Boot Menu]
3. Select **Low-resolution video (640x480)**

if that fails retry with

4. Safe mode

If that fails leave a comment, and I will add further instructions.

Comment: There is no VGA mode and I am able to get into safe mode w/ networking etc..

Comment: @Usernamehere  Sorry its "Low-resolution video..."

Comment: I clicked enable low-resolution video and it went direct to blue screen then booting into safe mode works.

Comment: is there anything to do in safe mode?

Comment: @Usernamehere - I would use windbg to determine the cause of the crash, which is more likely a driver, and then make sure that driver isn't loaded.  The reason Safe Mode worked is likely that problem driver was not loaded

Comment: I had no problem getting into safe mode, I just want to know how the process above would help? I can't find windbg for windows 7 for some reason, only windows 10.

Comment: You can uninstall your graphics drivers, and start fresh.http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html

Comment: I tried that already, its on my original post. Well I've tried reinstalling back to factory default, hasn't worked, but a new error 0x0000003B.

Comment: Well trying to reinstall the os was a bad idea, now I can't get into safe mode or anything, as it requires a restart. Thanks for the help fellas, don't think I can salvage this. Not sure why integrated graphics didn't kick in.

Comment: @Usernamehere What is the error?  Did you check the temperature reading from the CPU and GPU?  See if either is overheating.

Comment: System temp is 35 Celsius and CPU is 63 Celsius. There is no temp for gpu.

Comment: Error is bsod with 0x0000003B in place of 0x000000116